# Getting Google contacts from access token in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth, google-contacts-api, google-oauth

I have a rails app that has google Login. I am using a 'omniauth-google-oauth2' gem. After authorization from user, i am getting the credentials in the form of OmniAuth::AuthHash.

I am planning to use "google_contacts_api" to get the contacts for the user, This requires me to have a OAuth2::AccessToken to get contacts. And in order to create the same, i need OAuth2::Client to create the AccessToken. I was wondering

1. How to create client using the OmniAuth Strategy and second
2. Is there a better way to create OAuth2::AccessToken?

Answer (score 0):

**1. How to create client using the OmniAuth Strategy?**

Based from this [documentation](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Strategy-Contribution-Guide), you'll first need an API endpoint that will return the resource owner's credentials to create a strategy for your provider. You need to define the class and include the proper module. If you define your class in the `OmniAuth::Strategies`, namespace will allow it to be declared by symbolic name instead of class in an `OmniAuth::Builder` call.

```
require 'omniauth'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Developer
      include OmniAuth::Strategy
    end
  end
end
```

Check this [tutorial](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/create-a-omniauth-strategy-for-your-provider) and related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707734/refresh-token-using-omniauth-oauth2-in-rails-application/23254897#23254897).

**2. Is there a better way to create OAuth2::AccessToken?**

To use [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), you must register your project in the Google [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console#access) and enable the Contacts API service. You need to get a 'refresh token' that you use to 're-authenticate' with google each time you make an API call. You can check the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798574/cannot-get-oauth2-access-token-for-google-analytics-api).

Hope this helps! :)