# does authorization code for gmail oauth2 ever expires

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap, aspose

I am trying to use **gmail smtp** using **oauth 2.0**. I have used **aspose.dll** for requesting access token using authorization url. I do not get refresh token when i get the response.so there is no way to request new access token if previous is expired. So i thought of getting access token every-time my app requires . And if authorization code gets expired then i can not follow this approach.

does authorization code for gmail oauth2 ever expires??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google's OAuth 2.0 does provide Refresh Tokens!!! This [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) here explains the various flows and talks about apps obtaining both access and an optional refresh token for all scenarios.

**Authorization code DOES expire**! That's what OAuth protocol dictates. I cannot find an exact time period to quote here for Google, but I do know that for [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/)), the authorization code expires in 10 minutes (See the december 5 change in the link.). 
The Refresh Token has been made available for use cases like yours. If the authorization code were to persist, what difference would remain between a Refresh token and Authorization code.

I'd suggest you look up the documentation of the Aspose libraries you are using.

PS - Authorization code/access tokens/refresh tokens are all issued by a central Google Authorization server! So, we're talking about Google's Authorization code which, as I said, does expire.

Good luck!

**EDIT - Adding more info for you**

> ```
>      The authorization code generated by the
>      authorization server.  The authorization code MUST expire
>      shortly after it is issued to mitigate the risk of leaks.  A
>      maximum authorization code lifetime of 10 minutes is
>      RECOMMENDED.  The client MUST NOT use the authorization code
>      more than once.  If an authorization code is used more than
>      once, the authorization server MUST deny the request and SHOULD
>      revoke (when possible) all tokens previously issued based on
>      that authorization code.  The authorization code is bound to
>      the client identifier and redirection URI.
> ```

Source - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31 
Section - 4.1.2

Comment: thanks,do you know any .net library that'll get me both access and secret token.

Comment: I'm afraid not. But google does provide it's own dotnet API for OAuth, why don't you use that. http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2 This link also has some samples, you might want to go through them

Comment: but they have not mentioned anywhere about getting access and refresh token both.

Comment: they have mentioned - Once you get an authorization code, you can use this code to get a refresh-token and an access-token. An access token is usually valid for a maximum of one hour, and allows you to access the user's data. Every time you make a request to protected data, you have to authorize the request using an access token.!!! But alas, even I don't see any code samples where they've fetched the refresh token. I'll let you know if I could find a sample.

Comment: You might want to see this too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/google-oauth-refresh-token-is-not-being-received