# OAuth2.0 cannot get refresh token even when access_type=offline

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I see on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) that you need to set `access_type=offline` in order to get refresh token.

I did set this value in OAuth url and I clearly see it properly set along with other parameters. However, I still don't get refresh token back as a response. I copy & pasted OAuth2 related code from [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this the first time you are authorizing with the application since you changed the parameter to `access_type=offline`? You will only retrieve refresh token once when client clicks authorization button to grant you access.

One workaround is to set another parameter `approval_prompt=force` so that user will always click on authorization button and you can always get refresh token. Otherwise, save refresh token locally so that you don't have to retrieve it again.

Comment: Please save the refresh token locally and do not repeatedly generate refresh tokens for the same user. Google enforces a token cap for each user. Things will break unexpectedly in weird manner when that happens.

Comment: A related and very useful thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/google-oauth-refresh-token-is-not-being-received. I have something like `if DEBUG: flow.params['approval_prompt'] = 'true'` when I am developing locally.

Comment: approval_prompt=force no longer works