# Refresh token is not returned after initial authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

This is a follow up to question [Not receiving Google OAuth refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/google-oauth-refresh-token-is-not-being-received)

The answer is "The refresh_token is only provided on the first authorization from the user."

After revoking rights for the app and trying to authorize again, refresh token is not returned. What I get is:

`{
  "access_token" : "XXXX..",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "id_token" : "XXXX..."
}`

Others suggested to use `access_type=offline` however, according to description offline access is used if:

> "application needs to access a Google API when the user is not present
>   at the browser"

which isn't the case for me.

What is a proper way to get refresh token?

Comment: Is this using the web server flow, or javascript client flow?

Comment: This is done one a server. Specifically I am using opauth library http://opauth.org/

Comment: then @jay's answer applies. You will only get a refresh token if both (a) you have requested one with access_type=offline *and* (b) the user specifically granted it (ie. initial grant, or approval_prompt = force)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get a refresh token if access_type=offline is set. You have two choices of how to handle this:

1. Don't use `access_type=offline`. Your access token will be good for 1 hour. After the access token expires, re-prompt the user to authenticate again. They'll need to do the whole OAuth dance again so that you can get a new access token.
2. Use `access_type=offline` so that you can [get a new access tokens via the refresh token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh). If you prefer, after the user logs out, you can [revoke the tokens](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke).

Comment: While testing this, I am revoking application's access and user does go through authentication screen. However, I still don't get refresh_token.

Comment: you only get a refresh token if access_type=offline is set.

Answer (score 1):

**Every time When you reload you application page , Access Token is Refreshed or you can say the refresh token for this purpose you should use the following** but First You Need the authentication

```
  gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
```

**i am also doing the same thing by the following Way**

```
   var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
```

You can use this to avoid your problem "refresh token is not returned".

Thank You!!

Comment: This is the client side Javascript Way