# Unable to get refresh token with google OAuth 2

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token

**Situation**

I have simple android app where user gets data from [Google Fusion Tables](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) with REST api. For this I was using OAuth 2 authorization to get Access Token and Refresh Token. I have web view in my app which will show login screen as well as consent screen. I was planning to get access token from web view and use it for further API calls. I am using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to execute my http calls. I use following query parameters,

```
"client_id" = CLIENTID
"client_secret" = SECRET
"code" = 4/XXXXXXXXXX  //Code got from redirect url
"grant_type" = "authorization_code"  
"access_type" = "offline"
"approval_prompt" = "force"
"redirect_uri" = REDIRECT_URL
```

So far so good. But when I exceute post request with above query parameters, I get following response,

```
{
  "access_token": "ya29.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "id_token": "XXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

**Question**

Where is refresh token? I need refresh token because I couldn't do API call through app later on with access token and I don't want user to get access token every time.

**What I have tried**

I have already followed instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/google-oauth-refresh-token-is-not-being-received) post and have tried revoking permission to application from settings. I have also tried using different google accounts in case there was some permission issue, but still no luck. I have also tried removing query parameter "approval_prompt" and "grant_type" but that also didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got answer after searching and banging head for 5-6 hours. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34235680/5284595) answer saved me! Answer to people looking for this in future,

Add "access_type" = "offline" query while **requesting** for access token rather than **exchanging**, i.e. in URL which asks for consent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying `grant_type=offline` in the authorization request, you need to provide `access_type=offline` to request a refresh token.

Comment: Sorry, I had typo while writing. I have edited question. "access_type=offline" query is already there !