# RefreshToken Not getting send back after I get new token google sheets API

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

I am using the google sheets API with PHP and followed the quick start guide that can be found over here https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php

When I do authorize properly and store the follow json file in a speicfied path

```
{
  "access_token": "xxxxxxx",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "xxxxxx",
  "created": 1472731452
}
```

After this expires the following gets triggered in my code

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken(
        $client->getRefreshToken()
    );

    $this->filesystem
        ->put(
            self::CREDENTIALS,
            json_encode($client->getAccessToken())
        );
}
```

Now my issue is when that code gets triggered it will update my file to something like the following.

```
{
  "access_token": "xxxxxxx",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "created": 1472731452
}
```

As you can see there is no refresh token anymore. When this token expires I start getting the following error

```
[LogicException]
refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken
```

Which is perfactly understandable because I don't have the refresh token there anymore.

My question is why is the refresh token getting removed? I am call the same methods as the one in the quick start guide https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php

I am talking specificaly about this part in the guide

```
// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
  file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [refresh token expired](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/refresh-token/) because the lifespan set in your code was 3600 seconds only/1 hour.

```
{
"access_token": "xxxxxxx",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 3600, //refresh_token good for 1 hour
"refresh_token": "xxxxxx",
"created": 1472731452
}
```

[Using a refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#refresh)

A refresh token is obtained in offline scenarios during the first authorization code exchange. In these cases, your application may obtain a new access token by sending a refresh token to the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization server.

To obtain a new access token this way, your application sends an HTTPS POST request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token. The request must include the following parameters:

Such a request will look similar to the following:

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
refresh_token=1/6BMfW9j53gdGImsiyUH5kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token) for additional reference.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does, much more clearer, thank you! I just re-attached the refresh token before saving it :)