# App Service Refresh Tokens

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

Has anything changed with regard to refreshing Google tokens using the MobileServiceClient against App Service.  I used to be able to refresh Google tokens in my Xamarin Forms app using the MobileServiceClient.  Now, after logging in, any attempt to refresh returns forbidden.

My login code is as follows:

```
public class Authentication : IAuthentication
{
    public async Task<MobileServiceUser> LoginAsync(MobileServiceClient mobileClient, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider)
    {
        return await mobileClient.LoginAsync(
            Forms.Context, 
            provider, 
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "access_type", "offline" }
            });
    }
}
```

My refresh code is:

```
var user = await MobileService.RefreshUserAsync();
```

The refresh fails even if I try refreshing immediately after my successful login.  The `Token Store` is configured "On".  The refresh works fine against the Microsoft provider.  It was working a few months ago.

Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client v3.1.0
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server v2.0.0

Browsing directly to https://[my-website].azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google returns "You have successfully signed in"

Browsing directly to https://[my-website].azurewebsites.net/.auth/me returns [{"access_token":"ya29.Gl3ZAw6B1H0cT_e6vRlHgwQd0U-bcDSKo_CGQ9wKwPH8H-EbtNojP61JSzDaiIgSzU14PrT3QRb14NsFPhFYrU8ikCPGkhwKkZMAtHCNSdzDhTPm5cl89VrAlNc3vRU","expires_on":"2017-01-20T15:00:21.3928445Z","id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZlYzMwOTBlZjgyM2YxMWFhN2VhNDE0N2FlZWM1Zjk0YmViNWZkMDMifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE0ODQ5MjA4MjEsImV4cCI6MTQ4NDkyNDQyMSwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IlhHa3dqOFpiZU9GX2N3SmpqeEpMRnciLCJhdWQiOiI3NDgwNzM0Njg2NDktanRtNTl0N21sY3NjaTg5bG9rYnV2c2VvYW5uMjhiZ3EuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiIxMDE4MTI5MTIzODE5MTgwNDA4NDciLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXpwIjoiNzQ4MDczNDY4NjQ5LWp0bTU5dDdtbGNzY2k4OWxva2J1dnNlb2FubjI4YmdxLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJnY3JvY2tlbmJlcmdAZ21haWwuY29tIiwibmFtZSI6ImdlcmFyZCBjcm9ja2VuYmVyZyIsInBpY3R1cmUiOiJodHRwczovL2xoNS5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20vLVpINUxBQ1RhQTRJL0FBQUFBQUFBQUFJL0FBQUFBQUFBQUFBL0FLQl9VOHRpamZ5ZUN3Qk9tWUxzTmM4QUZJcTNDVGJhVHcvczk2LWMvcGhvdG8uanBnIiwiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6ImdlcmFyZCIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiY3JvY2tlbmJlcmcifQ.Qie3hRwKP-mbzMp3gzWatmQdLLVw3Ae7PXw1Ly8Se7-EQWBPgky0TsQ-fvZIasiHaq1tQu9lXyNu9qYqaaAvKxKCGxRE5yYhC76Yar_rQig14lf42bMRYQ3ADzwsPZ0yUbEpk-h4_HU5Ld1lNqYG-hgzEdUsJm_uspJk7FggwcfuPw-YQJr-GXbqd2Om9fmgGPrPrsFy7EzPGL27q_BIY3cOLEVX0e3tbAAVhxFCri835nBKdkYOP9X2g6wSuMWCq6iPOjFzErhVYR_WUwi5H-UW6mJHswcAfs_3Hwwt9RzCqfcyS1ZaehQVJE5B3uvK9WmAOrbD7uyEQmSli_zRWw","provider_name":"google","user_claims":[{"typ":"iss","val":"https://accounts.google.com"},{"typ":"iat","val":"1484920821"},{"typ":"exp","val":"1484924421"},{"typ":"at_hash","val":"XGkwj8ZbeOF_cwJjjxJLFw"},{"typ":"aud","val":"748073468649-jtm59t7mlcsci89lokbuvseoann28bgq.apps.googleusercontent.com"},{"typ":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier","val":"101812912381918040847"},{"typ":"email_verified","val":"true"},{"typ":"azp","val":"748073468649-jtm59t7mlcsci89lokbuvseoann28bgq.apps.googleusercontent.com"},{"typ":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress","val":"[my-googleemail]"},{"typ":"name","val":"[my - name]"},{"typ":"picture","val":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ZH5LACTaA4I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKB_U8tijfyeCwBOmYLsNc8AFIq3CTbaTw/s96-c/photo.jpg"},{"typ":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname","val":"[my-givenname]"},{"typ":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname","val":"[my-surname]"}],"user_id":"[my-googleemail]"}]

Browsing directly to https://[my-website].azurewebsites/.auth/refresh returns **"You do not have permission to view this directory or page"**

**If I repeat those steps with "microsoftaccount" the last refresh step works**.

From Azure request tracking:
107.  -GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_START
0 ms

Informational
108.  -GENERAL_RESPONSE_HEADERS
Headers
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-FE-DATA: AppId:Unknown-StatusCode
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
DWAS-Handler-Name: BEGIN|403|80|0x0|CONFIG_SUCCESS|ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0|###.##.##.###|\###.##.##.##\volume-4-default\&ApiApp=0
0 ms

Verbose
109.  -GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER
Buffer
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
0 ms

Informational
110.  -GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_END
BytesSent 400
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully.
           (0x0)

Comment: Could you access your mobile back-end in the browser directly and login in with your account. Then try to access `https://{your-appname}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` to retrieve your logged information.  Also, try to access `https://{your-appname}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/refresh` to refresh the access token. Make sure the `Token Store` is configured as "On" under the section "Authentication/Authorization > Advanced Settings"  of your app service in Azure Portal.

Comment: Additionally, you could leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the detailed response when you refresh token by your code. If possible, please update your question with the detailed error message.

Comment: Requested information added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that, with Google logins, refresh tokens are only issued upon the first login.  I moved my Azure website and repointed the OAuth client settings so I was able to login but the `Token Store` no longer had a copy of the `refresh_token` sent with my initial Google login.  Found the rest of the answer here.

[Not receiving Google OAuth refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token)

Answer (score 0):

According to your detailed information, I noticed that when you browsing directly to https://[my-website].azurewebsites.net/.auth/me, the response did not contain `refresh_token`. To isolate this issue, you could refer the following steps:

1.Browser https://brucechen-mobile.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google?access_type=offline and login with google account;

2.Access [/.auth/me](https://brucechen-mobile.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me) to retrieve my logged information as follows:

[image]

3.Browser [/.auth/refresh](https://brucechen-mobile.azurewebsites.net/.auth/refresh) to see whether you could get the response with 200 http status code.

Also, you could follow this official [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/mobile-apps-easy-authentication-refresh-token-support/) about refreshing user logins in App Service Mobile Apps to troubleshoot this issue. Additionally, you could leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the detailed response when you invoke `MobileService.RefreshUserAsync()`.

Comment: I do see the `refresh_token` when accessing your `/.auth/me` after authenticating to Google.  I'll keep digging into why I am not receiving the `refresh_token` in my azurewebsites response after logging into Google.  I do receive the `refresh_token` after authenticating with `microsoftaccount`.