# oauth2client.client - Received token response with no refresh_token. Consider reauthenticating with prompt='consent'

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I received google auth code from mobile app and use python oauth2client to exchange to access token and refresh token as follow:

```
credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
                        app.config.get('GG_APP_SECRET'),
                        ['profile'],
                        authCodeFromMobileApp,
                        redirect_uri='http://example.com')
```

Then I received:

> Received token response with no refresh_token. Consider
>   reauthenticating with prompt='consent'.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token) it said that I have to set: `access_type=offline` But I'm not really sure where/how in oauth2client to set this?

Anyone here ever solve this issue before?

Addition:

I have tried below as well:

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(app.config.get('GG_APP_SECRET'),
                                      ['profile'],
                                      message=None,
                                      cache=None,
                                      redirect_uri='http://example.com',
                                      device_uri=None)
flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(req_gg_code, http=None)
```

But still having the same unexpected result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flow_from_clientsecrets method has parameter called **prompt** which you can pass a value **"consent"**

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
            app.config.get('GG_APP_SECRET'),
            ['profile'],
            message=None,
            cache=None,
            redirect_uri='http://example.com',
            device_uri=None,
            prompt='consent'
)
```

Now, it will ask for Users consent every time, and you would get a **refresh_token** every time to use.