# Authenticate with Google on the web (javascript), consume on the server (.NET)

Tags: javascript, c#, google-signin, google-oauth, google-client

We have a web server using [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) to authenticater and authorize for API access (Classroom). We need the sign-in part, so we're using [`init()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initparams) and [`signIn()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsignin). We cannot use [`authorise()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authorizeparams-callback). Also, we're not signin in with particular scopes, as we just need identify for normal usage.

The logged-in user can enable a feature that requires offline access on behalf of his/her account to the Google Classrom API. We call [`grantOfflineAccess()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergrantofflineaccessscopes) with two scopes related to Classroom to get an authentication code, which is stored for later.

On the server side, we have a gRPC service that doesn't expose any web front-end. We're using C#/.NET with the [Google API Client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/).

I implemented an `IDataStore` that can respond to `TokenResponse` requests by either calling [AuthorizationCodeFlow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.10.0/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1Flows_1_1AuthorizationCodeFlow#ae800a73ce82d01e0329e19cc68b02a2c) with the above code, or return the last `TokenResponse` stored in the database. When (well, "if") `IDataStore.StoreAsync` is called with a new version (normally after a token refresh was required), it saves it again in the database.

My problem is that `ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync` returns me a `TokenResponse` without a `refresh_token`. This means the `access_token` is only valid for 60 minutes. I would need to intercept exceptions at the service call level to call `ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync` again (if that works!), instead of relying on the Google API Client Library handling refreshing automatically all nicely.

What could be preventing `ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync` from returning me a `refresh_token`?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to sign in via the JS libraries? Can't you just do a full server-side sign-in process? In which case your server will already have the token passed to it by Google from the Google Sign in page. Pretty sure this is documented in the API docs. Perhaps I missed something in your requirements. Edit: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer documents a full server-side OAuth flow. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow documents a hybrid approach using both JS and server-side.

Comment: a) To authenticate users. b) We do make API calls in the client app as well. c) The service is a gRPC service without a public front, running maintenance operations periodically.

Comment: By the way, I did manage to make it work since I posted, pretty much like @ADyson 's second link, but the response does not have a refresh_token. My API calls work, but I'm waiting an hour to see what happens after expiration.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857806/4898).

> The refresh_token is only provided on the first authorization from the user. Subsequent authorizations, such as the kind you make while testing an OAuth2 integration, will not return the refresh_token again. :)

I simply removed my app from my Google account's authorized apps, and my next `ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync` call returned me a `refresh_token`.