# Refresh token is null from my google php client

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-php-sdk

I am trying to get refresh token for the authentication using `Google_Client` class. Here's how I am trying to do.
using package `"google/apiclient": "^2.2",`

```
$client = new \Google_Client($config);
$client->setAccessType("offline"); 
$client->setState('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
var_dump($client->authenticate('<auth_token_goes_here>');); // dumps array which has id_token, access_token , expires_in, token_type & created
var_dump($googleClient->getAccessToken()); // dumps array which has id_token, access_token , expires_in, token_type & created
var_dump($googleClient->getRefreshToken()); // returns null
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Alas! This StackOverflow post helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token .

Comment: hey. i am suing ur paytm package. i have done evrythng as u said. but wen i click the pay now button the page shows "transaction being processed" and then redirects me to a blank page like payment/api/status. why is it not taking me to paytm website?