# Chronic timeout issue with Google's API via python?

Tags: django, google-api, google-oauth, django-allauth, google-python-api

I am working on a little web app to help me manage my gmail. I have set it up through Google's API with the following function using the OAuth token I received through `django-allauth`.

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
from .choices import GMAIL
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialToken, SocialAccount
from apiclient.discovery import build


def get_credentials(user):
    account = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=user.id)
    token = SocialToken.objects.get(app=GMAIL, account=account).token
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(token)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    return service
```

This seems to work sometimes, but unfortunately, it isn't very reliable. It times out frequently at the `build()` function, only succeeding about a third of the time. I am wondering what could cause this behavior and if there is a more reliable way to access the API?

I found the following `AuthorizedSession` class from [these docs](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#requests):

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)

response = authed_session.request(
    'GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b')
```

But I don't know how to turn it into the kind of object that works with Google's API:

```
def get_labels(user):
    service = get_credentials(user)
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])
    return labels
```

Unfortunately, [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django) recommend using a deprecated package that I was hoping to avoid.

This is my first time really using an OAuth-enforced API. Does anyone have any advice?

EDIT: I posted after trying from my Macbook. I tried it on my Windows machine as well, where it works more consistently, but it takes about 20 seconds each time just to do `build()`. I feel like I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working much better this morning after I finally added the refresh token into the mix. Perhaps it's absence was causing some issues on the other end. I will continue testing, but it everything is working well right now:

Here is my full solution:

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

from apiclient import errors, discovery

from myproject.settings import GMAIL_CLIENT_API_KEY, GMAIL_CLIENT_API_SECRET


def get_credentials(user):
    token_set = user.socialaccount_set.first().socialtoken_set.first()
    token = token_set.token
    refresh_token = token_set.token_secret
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        token,
        refresh_token=refresh_token,
        client_id=GMAIL_CLIENT_API_KEY,
        client_secret=GMAIL_CLIENT_API_SECRET,
        token_uri= google.oauth2.credentials._GOOGLE_OAUTH2_TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
    )

    if credentials.expired:
        request = Request()
        credentials.refresh(request)

    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    return service
```

As you can see, I added my API keys into my settings file and referenced them here. I happened to stumble upon the `token_uri` while nosing around in the source files yesterday. The `refresh_token` was the piece that took the longest to find.

The good news is that django-allauth will save the refresh token to `SocialToken` model under the `token_secret` column. However, it will only do this if the following is in your settings:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'offline',
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, the `access_type` in `AUTH_PARAMS` must be set to `'offline'` [according to the docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#django-configuration).

Now, this will still give you trouble if you connected your account before you implemented this change, so you'll also need to revoke access to your app through your [Google permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/permissions) to obtain a new refresh token. More about that can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token).

I'm not sure if this is the proper/intended way of doing this, but until Google updates their docs for Django, this approach should work at least for testing purposes.

Comment: Follow up- I am going to leave this up for my own reference at least, but this didn't end up solving the original problem. I am having some sort of issue with respect to the particular local network that seems to be causing this problem.