# Google Play developer API not returning refresh token

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I want to get subscription data using [Purchase.Subscription](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions#resource) API. For this I am trying to get token from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization) ,It should return me following response:

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.ZStBkRnGyZ2mUYOLgls7QVBxOg82XhBCFo8UIT5gM",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "1/zaaHNytlC3SEBX7F2cfrHcqJEa3KoAHYeXES6nmho"
}
```

But when I tried to follow same steps, I am not getting **refresh_token** field in response.
I am sending below fields as mentioned in documentation:

```
grant_type=authorization_code
code=<the code from the previous step>
client_id=<the client ID token created in the APIs Console>
client_secret=<the client secret corresponding to the client ID>
redirect_uri=<the URI registered with the client ID>
```

Please help me what I am missing.

Comment: please post some of your code here

Comment: and what are you getting in return ?

Comment: I have already mentioned above that response is same as described in documentation except refresh_token is coming

Answer (score 1):

ok. I found actual issue. This is really lack of documentation on API side. We will have refresh_token value only for first time calling api https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token with below data after allowing app to manage your developer account:

```
grant_type=authorization_code
code=<the code from the previous step>
client_id=<the client ID token created in the APIs Console>
client_secret=<the client secret corresponding to the client ID>
redirect_uri=<the URI registered with the client ID>
```

If you are not getting refresh_token, you can follow steps as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token) and try to fetch refresh_token again