# How to reset Google API project

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-console-developer

In my google project (which is only in development yet, so I've just a dummy user), I have registered a few users using oAuth2.

The first time I registered the users, I got the refresh_token back, but I didn't save it... So now I want to "reset" the project's registered users, so that google sends me the refresh_token again.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857806/13013715). So it should work just with removing the permission for the single app.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially create a new OAuth 2.0 Client ID for the project. This should force the client to go through the user consent flow again at which point you could access the refresh token.

Comment: I did so, but I wasn't asked to allow access to my scopes while logging in again with all the accounts... And I didn't get the refresh_token back. Anyways, thank you; I should already have thought about it before asking the question...