# refresh_token is missing in Google OAuth2 .Net HttpPost request for access_token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, access-token, google-api-dotnet-client, refresh-token

In my Google OAuth request using .Net HttpPost refresh_token value is missing.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code
[image]

My input HTTP post request -

```
...google oauth post request details..url - (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token)...
and the postData - (client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret_key>&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=<redirect_url>&code=<authorization_code>&access_type=offline&prompt=consent&approval_prompt=force)
```

**Note: I have a valid response with access_token. However, refresh_token object value with empty record.**

Please help.

I already reviewed these links - [Not receiving Google OAuth refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token)

Answer (score 2):

The call to exchange the authorization code for an access token and refresh token looks as follows.

```
HTTP POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri={redirectURI}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

You dont use `access_type , approval_prompt, prompt` as part of the exchange for the authorization code those are included in the HTTP GET request that shows the consent screen.

Here you can add access_type, if you have created web credentials client on google developer console.

```
HTTP GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code&access_type=offline
```

If your interested in seeing how the calls are built up this might help. [Understanding Google OAuth 2.0 with curl](https://youtu.be/hBC_tVJIx5w)

Comment: Below response objects only created for request - refresh_token object itself missing!  
({
"access_token": {values},
"expires_in": 3599,
"scope": {url},
"token_type": "Bearer",
"id_token": "values"
})
Does id_token is the refresh_token?

Comment: id token is open id connect and not oauth2

Comment: Looks like an issue only with my account used to authorize OAuth. Note my account is used for the Google Play console and API access only to Google Play Android Developer API. Am I missing any permission?

Comment: Your client id and client secrete were created here right  https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard which type of client did you create?

Comment: Yes. OAuth 2.0 and enabled only with Google Play Android Developer API Service.

Comment: I still need help. refresh_token missing for only with my account :(

Comment: Have you tried removing consent and then authorizing it again [apps with consent](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en)