# How to get Google API refresh token from Firebase Auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-chrome, google-api

I'm building a chrome extension in React using Firebase Auth for login. The google api access token expires after 1 hour and I can't use the gapi client library in a chrome extension.

As such I'm manually refreshing the token by calling google's api. However, how do I get access to the refresh token?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token) post, a refresh token is returned only after the first sign in, so I used the instructions to remove access and re-prompt permissions. Console.logging credential returned the following but no refresh token:

```
accessToken: "ya29..."
idToken: "eyJhbGciOiJSUz..."
pendingToken: null
providerId: "google.com"
signInMethod: "google.com"
```

**Sign In code:**

```
const login = async () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
}
```

Any idea how to get the google api refresh token?