# Google Identity Services SDK - authorization code model in popup mode - how to request refresh/access tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement the authorization code model using the Google Identity Services SDK, as described in [Use Code Model](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model). I would like to use the popup mode.

I managed to initialize the code client and receive an auth code with this Javascript code:

```
tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  scope: SCOPES,
  callback: '', // defined later
  ux_mode: 'popup',
})

...

tokenClient.requestCode({prompt: 'consent'});
```

When I receive the auth code in my callback, I relay it to an endpoint on my platform, as described in [Step 5: Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code) and I try to exchange the auth code for a refresh and access token in Python:

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=scopes,
    state=state
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri
)

flow.fetch_token(code=code)
```

The problem is that I use this code with an empty redirect_uri, I get an error "missing redirect_uri parameter". If I specify a redirect URL defined in Google Cloud Console, I get an error "redirect_uri mismatch". And if I try to use the same redirect_uri as the one sent in the initial popup request (Google seems to use `storagerelay://...` in this case), I get an error that "it doesn't comply with Google Oauth2 policy".

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that in any authorization flow when you get an authorization code on the client side and then pass that to your server for token exchange you have to use the string literal `"postmessage"` as your setting for `redirect_uri`.

```py
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=scopes,
    state=state
    redirect_uri="postmessage"
)

flow.fetch_token(code=code)
```

This very important fact seems to be curiously absent from the documentation from most of the google client libraries, but it works for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow thanks! That worked great for me as well (I was about to give up and just use the redirect flow) Strange that it's nowhere to be found in the documentation.

Comment: This worked for me in the Node.js OAuth2Client constructor for calling OAuth2Client.getToken().