# Getting a Google API refresh token running on a non-local host

Tags: oauth2-playground

While testing my application at http://localhost:3000/ I was able to set up refresh_token and access_token generation. And my files attached in the form to send data are successfully sent to google drive.

Here is all my code

```js
import formidable from 'formidable';
import fs from 'fs';
import { google } from 'googleapis'
const stream = require('stream');

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
const REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
let REFRESH_TOKEN = process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN
let ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN

let bodyContent = `client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=${REFRESH_TOKEN}`;

const getTokens = () => {
    fetch("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: bodyContent,
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log(response)
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error('Ошибка при выполнении запроса');
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.access_token)
            ACCESS_TOKEN = data.access_token;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Произошла ошибка:', error);
        });
}

getTokens()

const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2({
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URI,
})

auth.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN, access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN })

const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

async function uploadFiles(file) {
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(`public/${file.name}`)
    const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough()
    bufferStream.end(fileContents)

    try {
        const response = await drive.files.create({
            media: {
                mimeType: 'application/pdf',
                body: bufferStream
            },
            requestBody: {
                name: file.name,
                parents: ["1WZj-6PV6sschMMBUFZax-O8ImCqTE7uC"]
            },
            fields: 'id,name'

        })
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data.id;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

async function sendDataToGoogleSheets(body, url) {
    const data = JSON.parse(body.formValues);

    const sheets = google.sheets({
        version: 'v4', auth
    })

    const urlLink = url ? `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${url}/view` : "Нет приложенного файла"
    try {
        const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId: "1AR32ZlUSU03QHPwRV64LyPmwhIlH5vGmLg60Ouq5mhI",
            range: "A1:F1",
            valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
            requestBody: {
                values: [
                    [data.name, data.email, data.phoneNumber, data.comment, data.resumeLink, urlLink]
                ]
            }
        })

        return response.data

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

const post = async (req, res) => {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
        let file = files ? files.file : null;
        try {
            if (file) {
                await saveFile(file).catch(console.error);
                const url = await uploadFiles(file).catch(console.error);
                await sendDataToGoogleSheets(fields, url).catch(console.error);

                await removeFile(file.name).catch(console.error);
            } else {
                await sendDataToGoogleSheets(fields).catch(console.error);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Failed to do shit', error.message);
            res.status(500).end('Unexpected error');
        }
        if (err) {
            res.status(err.statusCode || 500).send(err.message);
        } else {
            res.status(201).send('');
        }
    });
};

const saveFile = async (file) => {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
    fs.writeFileSync(`./public/${file.name}`, data, console.log('file saved'));
    await fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
    return;
};

const removeFile = async (fileName) => {
    await fs.unlink(`./public/${fileName}`, () => {
        console.log(`file ${fileName} removed`);
    });
    return;
};

const reqRes = (req, res) => {
    req.method === 'POST'
        ? post(req, res)
        : req.method === 'PUT'
            ? console.log('PUT')
            : req.method === 'DELETE'
                ? console.log('DELETE')
                : req.method === 'GET'
                    ? console.log('GET')
                    : res.status(404).send('');
};
export default reqRes;
export { config };
```

Then I deployed my test application to https://vercel.com/ and the files stopped being sent to google drive.

[My google spreadsheets screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CT9n.jpg)

The file is not sent to the Google spreadsheet, but the Google spreadsheet itself is filled

I tried to generate new refresh_token and access_token for the domain that vercel gave me.
But in response I get only access_token.
`{ "access_token": "ХХХХХ", "expires_in": 3599, "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "token_type": "Bearer" }`

In my code, to send a file to google drive, it is necessary to set the refresh_token and access_token, and this is how I pass them in the code
`auth.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN, access_token: AСCESS_TOKEN })`

But I don't receive a refresh_token at all for an application running on https://vercel.com/.

Who can tell me how to get all the necessary tokens correctly so that I can use it not only on the local host

Comment: When you say that files are not being sent to google drive, what error do you face? (use browser developer tools to inspect the network traffic and check)

Comment: Spelling is incorrect for `ACESS_TOKEN` just pointing out.. FYI

Comment: @Kartoos
When I run the application locally and send a file, I get the following logs in the console`file saved
ya29.XXXXXXX
{
  id: '16v-1jRsl_8aNyMZZv3VQHf7_r8_XFtds',
  name: 'CV Artem Yatsenko.pdf'
}
file CV Artem Yatsenko.pdf removed` . In the network tab, I see the status of my request 201. When submitting the form, I also fill the Google spreadsheet with this data. All completed fields are successfully transferred to the Google spreadsheet, but the file does not arrive. I also see errors in the network, status 201 issues

Comment: status 201 generally mean content successfully created. What kind of errors do you see in the network tab while uploading in your vercel hosted site? Can you share those errors by editing your question, so we can try to figure out your problem

Comment: When submitting a form from versel hosting, I don't see any errors in the response, I get a 201 status. Maybe I don't know how to view the response from the server. I look in the network tab and it says this `Request URL:
https://hr-navy.vercel.app/api/mailer
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 201
Remote Address: 76.76.21.61:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure how your code is written or in which framework. But I have tried to implement minimal working example of your code in Express.js using `.mjs` extension to enable ES6 `import` statements. Here is my `server.mjs` which is run using `node server.mjs` command:

```js
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import fs from 'fs';
import { google } from 'googleapis'
import stream from 'stream';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import formidable from 'formidable';

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
const REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
let REFRESH_TOKEN = process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN
let ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN

let bodyContent = `client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=${REFRESH_TOKEN}`;

const getTokens = () => {
    fetch("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: bodyContent,
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                // console.log(response)
                return response.json();
            } else {
                // console.log(response.status);
                // response.json().then(z => console.log(z));
                throw new Error('Ошибка при выполнении запроса');
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.access_token)
            ACCESS_TOKEN = data.access_token;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Произошла ошибка:', error);
        });
}

getTokens()

console.log(`CLIENT_ID: ${CLIENT_ID}`);
console.log(`CLIENT_SECRET: ${CLIENT_SECRET}`);
console.log(`REDIRECT_URI: ${REDIRECT_URI}`);

const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
})

auth.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN, access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN })

const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

async function uploadFiles(file) {
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(`public/${file.name}`)
    const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough()
    bufferStream.end(fileContents)

    try {
        const response = await drive.files.create({
            media: {
                mimeType: 'application/pdf',
                body: bufferStream
            },
            requestBody: {
                name: file.name,
                parents: ["1WZj-6PV6sschMMBUFZax-O8ImCqTE7uC"]
            },
            fields: 'id,name'

        })
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data.id;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

async function sendDataToGoogleSheets(body, url) {
    const data = JSON.parse(body.formValues);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(url);

    const sheets = google.sheets({
        version: 'v4', auth
    })

    const urlLink = url ? `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${url}/view` : "Нет приложенного файла"
    try {
        const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId: "1AR32ZlUSU03QHPwRV64LyPmwhIlH5vGmLg60Ouq5mhI",
            range: "A1:F1",
            valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
            requestBody: {
                values: [
                    [data.name, data.email, data.phoneNumber, data.comment, data.resumeLink, urlLink]
                ]
            }
        })

        return response.data

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

const post = async (req, res) => {
    const form = formidable();

    form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
        console.log(fields);
        let file = files ? files.file : null;
        try {
            if (file) {
                await saveFile(file).catch(console.error);
                const url = await uploadFiles(file).catch(console.error);
                await sendDataToGoogleSheets(fields, url).catch(console.error);

                await removeFile(file.name).catch(console.error);
            } else {
                await sendDataToGoogleSheets(fields).catch(console.error);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Failed to do shit', error.message);
            res.status(500).end('Unexpected error');
        }
        if (err) {
            res.status(err.statusCode || 500).send(err.message);
        } else {
            res.status(201).send('');
        }
    });
};

const saveFile = async (file) => {
    console.log(file.path, file.name);
    const data = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
    fs.writeFileSync(`./public/${file.name}`, data, console.log('file saved'));
    await fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
    return;
};

const removeFile = async (fileName) => {
    await fs.unlink(`./public/${fileName}`, () => {
        console.log(`file ${fileName} removed`);
    });
    return;
};

const reqRes = (req, res) => {
    req.method === 'POST'
        ? post(req, res)
        : req.method === 'PUT'
            ? console.log('PUT')
            : req.method === 'DELETE'
                ? console.log('DELETE')
                : req.method === 'GET'
                    ? console.log('GET')
                    : res.status(404).send('');
};
// export default reqRes;
// export { config };


app.use('/api', reqRes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

The above code is a local working example, you need to provide:

- `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET` (taken both from google console)
- `ACCESS_TOKEN`, `REFRESH_TOKEN` (taken both from OAuth playground by setting Redirect Url as https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground on google console and providing clientId and clientSecret by clicking gear icon on playground)
- `spreadsheetId` (taken from google sheet url after creating a sheet on
  your drive).

After running the above code, One can call the API from postman (or any client of choice) with form-data with key as `formValues` and value as stringified JSON. The following is sample cURL to call the API:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:4000/api' \
--form 'formValues="{\"name\":\"KK\",\"email\":\"KK@KK.com\",\"phoneNumber\":\"5467586795\",\"comment\":\"my comment\",\"resumeLink\":\"http://myresume.com\"}"'
```

---

## Possible Solutions

#### Pass clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri properly

I would say I have changed following line to make it work locally:

```js
const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
})
```

Because the clientId, clientSecret and redirectUri was not being passed to `const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });` drive object.

#### Pass environment variables to vercel deployment

Another reason this might not be working if you are not passing CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, and REFRESH_TOKEN via environment variable since your code expects this information via environment variables, which you might need to provide in vercel deployment. You can check [here](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables) about passing environment variables.

#### Check logs on vercel deployment and while the deployment is running

Also one observation is that the code is not written in a way to catch all the errors and conditions properly, you will get `201` even if it fails in the background, you might need to check vercel logs, I believe you can follow [this](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/observability/runtime-logs) and [this](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs) to get logs and understand the issue better.

#### Refresh tokens are not generated each time

Refresh tokens are [not really generated each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token) but generated first time only. So it is the expected response from google.