# Not getting refresh token for Google Calendar API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate google calendar in my app so that user can see their event and add event to their calendar for that

I have follow the Google quickstart guide for javascript
[Quickstart Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token)

the guide works fine and fetches all the events

and if you log the response you will get the access token with the below code

```
console.log("token",resp);
```

**The Problem**: the response does not include the refresh_token obj,and the access_token in response has an expiry of 60 min

What i tried so far:

```
tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent',access_type: 'offline'});
```

and

```
tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      callback: 'http://localhost:8000/callback', 
      access_type:'offline'
    });
```

added the access_type: 'offline' in both places ,

i have also tried removing the permission as suggested in this
[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token)

how can i get refresh_token in response?
Thanks!